# I have an error in my code. Something with pointers I can't seem to fix it

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, char

I was practicing pointers and classes and I tried to print the members of the class after I put a value. But an error appears that's something to do with pointers and the char array.

> Error (active) E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
> Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
> Error   C2664   'void car::setName(char [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'char []'
> Error   C2664   'void car::setColor(char [])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'char []'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class car {
private:
    char name[15];
    char color[10];
    int maxspeed;
    int model;

public:
    void setName(char  n[])
    {
        strcpy_s(name, n);
    }
    void setColor(char n[])
    {
        strcpy_s(color, n);
    }
    void setMaxspeed(int m)
    {
        maxspeed = m;
    }
    void setModel(int m)
    {
        model = m;
    }
    char* getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    char* getcolor()
    {
        return color;
    }
    int getMaxspeed()
    {
        return maxspeed;
    }
    int getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "name = " << name << "\n"
            << "color = " << color << "\n"
            << "Maxspeed = " << maxspeed << "\n"
            << "Model = " << model << "\n";
    }

};



int main()
{
    car x;
    x.setName("kia");
    x.setColor("red");
    x.setMaxspeed(300);
    x.setModel(2017);
    x.print();
    return 0;
 
}
```

Those are the errors I got
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTx7E.png)

Comment: "abcd" type is `const char*` not `char *`  This used to be acceptable a long, long time ago but c++ is stricter these days.

Comment: More accepted than acceptable. It was simply understood that no one would be dumb enough to point at read only memory with a writable pointer and actually write to it. Since time has shown that understanding is flawed and humans are often exactly that dumb, the modern compilers now enforce a rule that's been in place in the Language specification for decades.

Comment: Side note: Make sure you fully understand what `strcpy_s` is doing. If you're expecting it to prevent overflowing the buffer by simply not accepting more than it can eat, you could be in for a massive shock.

Comment: `"abcd"` is of type `const char[5]`, it isn't a pointer at all. Though it decays to a pointer trivially

Comment: For strings, I highly recommend `std::string` over a `char[]` array.  Especially for how you are using them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, `char*` (or `char[]`, as you wrote it) is a different type than `const char*` and string literals are of the latter. You can't pass a `const char*` to a function expecting `char*`.

If you rewrite your functions to take `const char*` or `const char[]`, it'll work:

```
    void setColor(const char n[])
    // ...
    void setColor(const char n[])
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you the problem fairly directly. You're trying to pass string literals to `setName` and `setColor`. To be compatible with a string literal, you need an argument of type `char const *` (or equivalently, `const char *`). But what you've used is `char []`, which (in the case of a function argument) is equivalent to `char *`.

So, change the arguments to `char const *`:

```
void setName(char const *n)
{
    strcpy_s(name, n);
}
```

Once you've done that, look up `std:string`, and (unless required for homework or similar) quit using raw pointers to `char`.